# How to add side menu on particular pages in angular without using auxiliary routes

Tags: html, angular

I am working on one application which has top nav menu which is always there on all the page and there is one page called customer profile(http://localhost:4200/profile) on which i am displaying Account Info,Change Password,Address etc as a Side Menu and when user click any of the one say Change-Password then url will change to http://localhost:4200/profile/change-password and if clicked Address then url changes to http://localhost:4200/profile/address.

Side menu should always be there till user is at /profile and display content of that selected menu(like change password or address etc).

I read about the auxiliary routes but in that i see URL is change something to http://localhost:4200/profile/change-password(profile-sidebar:side-menu).

But i don't want this(profile-sidebar:side-menu) thing is the URL.

Is there any other alternative way in angular to achieve the same thing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your problem is not very clear. Can you provide what you have done so far ?

Comment: i cannot share code here, but in short i want side menu on some section of application(like profile) where i can select the menu options and URL and data change according to that option.

Comment: You don't need to share all your code, just the relevant pieces. We are not going to re-create your issue rather we cannot recreate your issue since we don't know what the issue is. Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) StackBlitz is a good start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the side menu inside your root component and just display it if the route starts with '/profil' wich can be checked through the router service :

**component ts**

```
...

constructor(private router : Router){}

urlStartsWith(path : string) : boolean {
  return this.router.url.startsWith(path) ;
}
```

**component html**

```
...
<app-side-menu *ngIf="urlStartsWith('/profil')"></app-side-menu>
...
```

'app-side-menu' is your side menu selector.

Comment: Yes, It is working fine.
But not sure, it is recommended approach or not.

Comment: I used to use this approach in many applications and it works well, so I recommend it.